# Neptune Gremlin weird mergeE behavior, updates vertex instead of edge

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I think there's a bug in mergeE().  Here's my setup in neptune

```
g.V().hasLabel('mytestlabel').drop()

g.addV('mytestlabel').property(id, 'testA').property('timestamp', 1).as('a')
.addV('mytestlabel').property(id, 'testA2').property('timestamp', 1).as('a2')
.addE('mytestlabel').from('a').to('a2').property('timestamp', 2).valueMap(true)
```

This generates my simple 2-node graph with an edge, output as expected is:

```
{<T.label: 4>: 'mytestlabel', <T.id: 1>: 'testA', 'timestamp': [1]}
{<T.label: 4>: 'mytestlabel', <T.id: 1>: 'testA2', 'timestamp': [1]}
{<T.label: 4>: 'mytestlabel', <T.id: 1>: '2cc6d009-4138-8b71-c016-6aa58927fe2f', 'timestamp': 2}}
```

Now, let's update the edge's timestamp

```
g.mergeE([(T.label):'mytestlabel', (Direction.from): 'testA', (Direction.to):'testA2'])
.option(onMatch, ['timestamp': 3]).valueMap(true)
```

As expected we get

```
{<T.label: 4>: 'mytestlabel', <T.id: 1>: '2cc6d009-4138-8b71-c016-6aa58927fe2f', 'timestamp': 3}
```

Let's try an incorrect merge syntax; using the cardinality single syntax for vertexes

```
g.mergeE([(T.label):'mytestlabel', (Direction.from): 'testA', (Direction.to):'testA2'])
.option(onMatch, sideEffect(property(single, 'timestamp', 4)
                            .property(single, 'edgelabel', 'exists'))
.constant([:])).valueMap(true)
```

As expected, it errors out:

```
Property cardinality can only be set for a Vertex but the traversal encountered NeptuneEdge for key: timestamp
```

Double checking our vertexes, they haven't changed:

```
{<T.label: 4>: 'mytestlabel', <T.id: 1>: 'testA', 'timestamp': [1]}
{<T.label: 4>: 'mytestlabel', <T.id: 1>: 'testA2', 'timestamp': [1]}
```

Now, let's add a .V() to the front of the incorrect merge:

```
g.V().mergeE([(T.label):'mytestlabel', (Direction.from): 'testA', (Direction.to):'testA2'])
.option(onMatch, sideEffect(property(single, 'timestamp', 4)
                            .property(single, 'edgelabel', 'exists'))
.constant([:])).valueMap(true)
```

This works!  But in a weird way, our edge hasn't changed, but our vertexes have.  A `g.V()` and `g.E()` gives us:

```
{<T.label: 4>: 'mytestlabel', <T.id: 1>: 'testA', 'edgelabel': ['exists'], 'timestamp': [4]}
{<T.label: 4>: 'mytestlabel', <T.id: 1>: 'testA2', 'edgelabel': ['exists'], 'timestamp': [4]}
{<T.label: 4>: 'mytestlabel', <T.id: 1>: '2cc6d009-4138-8b71-c016-6aa58927fe2f', 'timestamp': 3}
```

It also seems that this "incorrect" query executed once per node, I'm guessing because of the `V()`.  Doing a `g.V().count` gave me `1280` exactly:
[image: butwhy]

I've fixed my code so that I'm not doing `.V().mergeE()` and it works fine now, but I wanted to know what was happening; I think this is a bug?  I can't think of why mergeEdge would ever update a vertex.

Originally I did `.V().mergeE()` since I was doing a big batch query and just left the `.V()` in there.  I was getting performance issues (I'm guessing because it was executing per node in the graph) as well as incorrect values on my vertex+edges.

edit: If you try this incorrect syntax when the edge doesn't exist, it will create the edge with no properties other than label/id.  If you have a 3 node graph (a-a2, a-a3), then it executes nodecount^2:
[image]

Comment: This does not seem like the proper behavior.  I was able to reproduce this issue on a 1.3.0.0 Neptune cluster and I have filed a ticket and I will let you know what we find

Comment: The root cause of this issue has been found in TinkerPop and the fix is in this PR: https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/pull/2487